# gzgetc sets EOF flag when last character is read

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm using [zlib](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip) to extract a gzipped file. I'm reading individual characters using `gzgetc`. After extracting the last valid character from the stream, `gzeof` return `true`. It was my understanding that this should only happen when reading past the end of the stream.

Is this expected behavior, or am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gzeof()` should return true only after trying to read past the end of the stream, as noted in the documentation in zlib.h.

What version of zlib are you using? There was a problem with `gzeof()` that was fixed in zlib 1.2.6.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using the default installed on Mac OS X 10.11.1, which seems to be 1.2.5. That explains it! I'm currently working around this by checking the return value of `gzgetc`, which is -1 when the end of the stream is reached.